# .NET Maui FilePicker results in This platform does not support this file type error for MacOS

Tags: .net-maui

I am building a desktop app in .NET Maui which targets Windows and MacOS.
When using the built-in FilePicker on Mac (Catalyst) I get the following error:

{System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This platform does not support this file type.    at Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FilePickerFileType.GetPlatformFileType(DevicePlatform platform)    at Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FilePickerFileType.get_Value()    at Microsoft.Maui.S…}

I have tried multiple file types, including  csv, jpg, text/csv but nothing works.

```
public async Task ImportCSV()
    {
        try
        {
            var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
                    new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
                    {
                        { DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".csv" } },
                        { DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] {"csv"} }
                    });

            PickOptions options = new()
            {
                PickerTitle = "Please select a csv file",
                FileTypes = customFileType
            };

            var file = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);

            if (file != null)
            {
                string filePath = AppStateService.fixMacFilePath(file.FullPath);

                AppStateService.AppState.csvFilePath = filePath;

                await InitiateCsvMapping();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I am running Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac Preview
Version 17.4 Preview (17.4 build 715)

The documentation does say that I should "Enable iCloud capabilities" but does not provide any links or other information regarding this. I did some digging, and found some documentation that says that it necessary to do this via the Entitlements.plist file (but there is none in the Maui project) and seems to only be relevant when publishing your app to the App store which I am not during development. I don't even care about iCloud right now. I just want to select a CSV file from my own desktop. Is this the problem? Thanks!!

[Here is the article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/icloud-capabilities)

Comment: Did anyone find any solution of this problem?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76533120/7977288) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76533120/7977288).

In short, you have to use [UT identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) for MacOS.

This should work for CSV.

```cs
var supportedFile = new[] { "public.comma-separated-values-text" };
var fileTypes = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
{
    { DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst, supportedFile }
});
var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
{
    FileTypes = fileTypes
});
```

Comment: lol can't see the reason for the downvote. I just tested it and it works

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it has something to do with ICloud. It is just the wrong file type. File types are different on MacOS.They are called UTypes.

I haven't tried but it is likely:

```
public.comma-separated-values-text
```

More Info here: [commaSeparatedText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551477-commaseparatedtext)

And maybe it is DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst instead of macOs.