# FilePicker throwing an exception on mac OS with .net MAUI

Tags: .net, macos, maui, filepicker

I have a problem with the "filepicker" on net maui. It works perfectly on windows but not on macos (maccatalyst).

```
var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
                {
                    PickerTitle = "Carica il PDF del tuo documento",
                    FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Pdf
                });

                if (result == null)
                    return;

                string PathFile = result.FullPath;
```

Does the code have to be different? Thank you.

I tried specifying xamarin.essentials but it didn't change anything

```
                var result = await Xamarin.Essentials.FilePicker.PickAsync(new Xamarin.Essentials.PickOptions
                {
                    PickerTitle = "Carica il PDF del tuo documento",
                    FileTypes = Xamarin.Essentials.FilePickerFileType.Pdf
                });

                if (result == null)
                    return;

                string PathFile = result.FullPath;
```

In the same app, I can download and I can open the window that makes me select where to save the file, so I don't think it's a problem of permissions.

Answer (score 1):

### Initial configuration

First of all, ensure you're calling that method in the Main Thread.

Secondly, notice that there is some setup to make the `FilePicker` work correctly on iOS/Mac Catalyst. Try adding this to your `Entitlements.plist`.

```
<key>com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.assets.music.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.personal-information.photos-library</key>
<true/>
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=macios#get-started)

If you don't have such file, create it under the folder `Platform/MacCatalyst`.

Some additional configuration may be needed in order to add the entitlements in your build chain:

Right click on your MAUI project -> Build -> MacCatalyst -> Bundle Signing -> add your `Entitlements.plist` to 'Custom Entitlements`.

[image: Setting custom entitlements]

### Enabling only specific files

If you specify `FileTypes` enum when calling `FilePicker.PickAsync` it seems to throw an `PlatformNotSupportedException` with this message: `This platform does not support this file type.` At the time of writing the latest MAUI stable version is 7.0.86.

For example, this won't work.

```cs
FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
{
    FileTypes = FilePickerFileType.Pdf // This cause the exception to be thrown
});
```

However, `FilePickerFileType` also has a constructor which takes `Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>` as value, where you can specify your types using UT identifiers for Mac OS ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html) you can find some examples).

So, to enable pdf for your Mac `FilePicker` you can write something like this:

```cs
try
{
    var supportedFile = new[] { "com.adobe.pdf" };
    var fileTypes = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
    {
        { DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst, supportedFile }
    });
    var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
    {
        FileTypes = fileTypes
    });
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ex: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Obviously, it will require some conditional compilation if you have to run it on multiple platforms.

Comment: tnx! if i don't have this file, i must create it?

Comment: yep! Under the folder `Platform/MacCatalyst`.

Comment: Please, notice that I made a typo in the name `Entitlements.plist`. Now it's correct. And you may need some [additional configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/entitlements) to add this file in your building process. At least you have to tell to the project that it has to [consume the entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/entitlements#consume-entitlements) defined in your file.

Comment: I tested it and it seems to work :)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>com.apple.security.assets.movies.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.assets.music.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.assets.pictures.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.personal-information.photos-library</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: this is my file (maybe something is useless - i would use only pdf).

then I set the project following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/entitlements#consume-entitlements

nothing is changed

Comment: lgtm. The only difference from mine is the DOCTYPE line. I have `<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">` but I think it's not relevant. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: i put a control with "try-catch" and the result is:
This platform does not support this file type.

Comment: Ok this is funny. I get your same error if I specify `PickOptions`. The error doesn't appear if I use the no parameters overload of `PickAsync`. I assume Mac OS can't filter by file type of MAUI developers didn't implement this function for Mac.

Comment: try
{
var supportedFile = new[] { ".pdf" };
var fileTypes = new FilePickerFileType(new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
{
{DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst, supportedFile }
});
var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync(new PickOptions
{
PickerTitle = "Carica il PDF del tuo documento",
FileTypes = fileTypes
});
if (result == null)
return;
PathFile = result.FullPath;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine("ex: "+ex.Message);
}

Now the window opens but no file is selectable (they remain gray).

Comment: try changing `supportedFile` initialization with this: `var supportedFile = new[] { "com.adobe.pdf" };`