# MAUI FilePicker on MacOs (MacCatalyst) does not return picked file. (returns null)

Tags: maui, mac-catalyst, filepicker

I am having the exact same issues explained in https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11088.

and checked [FilePicker throwing an exception on mac OS with .net MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76532956/filepicker-throwing-an-exception-on-mac-os-with-net-maui) answer added

```
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
<true/>
```

to **Entitlements.plist**

Dotnet workloads on development machine (Windows);

```
Installed Workload Id Manifest Version Installation Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------
maui-windows 8.0.6/8.0.100 VS 17.10.34607.79
maccatalyst 17.2.8022/8.0.100 VS 17.10.34607.79
android 34.0.79/8.0.100 VS 17.10.34607.79
ios 17.2.8022/8.0.100 VS 17.10.34607.79
```

and dotnet workloads on publishing machine (Mac);

```
Installed Workload Id Manifest Version Installation Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------
wasm-tools 8.0.2/8.0.100 SDK 8.0.200
macos 14.2.8022/8.0.100 SDK 8.0.200
maui-maccatalyst 8.0.6/8.0.100 SDK 8.0.200
maui-ios 8.0.6/8.0.100 SDK 8.0.200
maui-android 8.0.6/8.0.100 SDK 8.0.200
ios 17.2.8022/8.0.100 SDK 8.0.200
maui 8.0.6/8.0.100 SDK 8.0.200
```

There is a approved and merged PR for this issue; https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13814 and more over, this issue has been deemed as fixed on Jul 12, 2023 https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11088#event-9792279528 Alas, when I lookup the sources of relevant code area from Visual Studio I am not able to see fixed code. (Its just #if/#endif which is not there!)

The following code is used to pick text files;

Project is open source and repository address is; https://github.com/Buyukcaglar/UltimateRemote

https://github.com/Buyukcaglar/UltimateRemote/blob/main/Constants/FilePickerOptions.cs Line 15 & 264

```
public static PickOptions TextFileOptions = new()
{
PickerTitle = "Select a TXT file",
FileTypes = TxtFile,
}; 

private static readonly FilePickerFileType TxtFile = new FilePickerFileType(
new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
{
{ DevicePlatform.iOS, new[] { "public.text" } },
{ DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "text/plain" } },
{ DevicePlatform.WinUI, new[] { ".txt" } },
{ DevicePlatform.Tizen, new[] { "*/*" } },
{ DevicePlatform.macOS, new[] { "public.text" } },
{ DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst, new[] { "public.text" } }
});
```

https://github.com/Buyukcaglar/UltimateRemote/blob/main/Services/StorageContentFileService.cs Line 51:

```
var pickResult = await FilePicker.PickAsync(FilePickerOptions.TextFileOptions);
```

**FilePicker.PickAsync or FilePicker.Default.PickAsync** does not matter, result is null regardless.

Am I missing something, or doing anything wrong? Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Seems like there is still a bug here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15126

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Thank you for pointing it out. It seems that reported for .Net7 and bug still exists.

Comment: Correct, I checked with your project on .NET 8, it still happens unfortunately. In the linked issue there is a third-party package that could help for now. Hopefully we can get this resolved with .NET MAUI soon!